# How to enable code-first migrations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There are many examples out there [including this](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

The problem is that many of the commands are changed, different, or not included with Entity Frameworks.
Can someone tell me how to enable code-first migrations with my project?

I am using visual studio 2015 and the latest version of MVC. My project works on the first build, but then after I kill the app and add another model, I get an invalid column name or suggestion to enable code first migrations.

Comment: So did you `Enable-Migrations` from the Package Manager Console?

Comment: it gives me "The term 'enable-migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.At line:1 char:1"

Comment: Something is wrong. Does that still happen after restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: I restarted it and opened it an an administrator. It is now saying that i need to use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName.

Comment: I am still getting an invalid column name when I run my application though.

Comment: When you say "the latest version of MVC" it's not clear what you mean. What specific version are you using?

Comment: I am using MVC V5.2.3.0

Comment: got it. after adding code-first migrations, it just required me to go into my database and simply add the columns in by hand. fixed it up just right.

Comment: If you're using migrations, why are you modifying your database schema by hand?  That defeats the point of migrations.

Comment: That's what I don't understand. I added migrations and it still gives me invalid column name errors when I add a new variable to my identity class instead of just adding the column.

Comment: The procedure is to enable migrations, then each time you make a change to the model, you add a migration, then you update the database with that migration.  It isn't enough to simply enable migrations.

Comment: @Travis Now that your Package Manager Console is recognising EF commands, I suggest you restart the tutorial you linked to from scratch. It's up to date, so if anything doesn't work as described, don't forge on and try to hack your way out of it. You'll get in to a terrible mess and it will slow your learning.

Comment: @amy gotcha. That was the part that I missed. It works perfectly! spender, so I have learned. Thanks for the tip. I was getting confused at the start because there are a lot of docs out there and I wasn't sure which ones are still relevant and which ones are deprecated. Thanks again.